# php code turned gibberish?

Tags: php, html

I went to edit this PHP file - it's supposed to generate those captcha security images on contact forms - the images werent working, so I was going to see if there was a broken path or something i could fix simply.

But when I opened the file it looked like this:
http://mydomainsample.com/explosion/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-17%20at%209.34.14%20AM.png

complete gibberish.

Is it possible this happened somehow while downloading the file from the server?  I did not have ftp access to the site originally - we got control of the domain and transferred it from one host to another.

I used site sucker to backup the site before transferring, but it downloads php files as html files. you end up with filename.php.html.

in the past this has never turned the php into incomprehensible gibberish, so i dont understand why it did now.

Comment: My 0.02: that's a binary file, probably the captcha image. Not the php file you want to edit

Comment: The `%PNG` at the beginning is the start of a PNG file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you cannot use programs like "site sucker" to get PHP files.  This is because when you get a PHP file from a URL, the file is *executed*, and you're getting the output of the script.  That's why you get `.php.html`.

It doesn't "turn the php into incomprehensible gibberish", the server runs the script and you're getting the output.  Most of the time the output is HTML, which you can open as text.  In this case, the script's output is a PNG file, thus why you see "gibberish".  Rename the file to `.png`, then you'll see the image.

You *need* to get FTP access in order to get the PHP source.

Comment: I get that it is a png image - but what good does that do me? 
as far as i can tell absolutely none, considering i dont need the image itself, i need the php to generate it and validate the form submission.
Unless someone can come up with some way that having this png image benefits me, i believe this thread is finished.

Comment: @timatgetdim: Yeah, sorry.  You need ftp (or ssh or whatever) access to the server to get the actual PHP file.

Answer (score 2):

That's a PNG image, not PHP source code.

Answer (score 1):

The file actually looks like a PNG image, maybe you just downloaded output the PHP script has generated?